# Docker build in Github actions giving error standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

Tags: python, docker, github-actions, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Using Docker to build and deploy our application to the AWS ECS cluster.

The docker image is built in the Github actions and pushed to the AWS ECR.

But when the images are deployed to the ECS cluster, it gives the error

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

[image]

The content of the **Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9.11-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

ARG APP_USER=app
RUN groupadd -r ${APP_USER} && useradd --no-log-init -r -m -g ${APP_USER} ${APP_USER}

RUN set -ex \
    && RUN_DEPS=" \
    libpcre3 \
    mime-support \
    libmagic1 \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    inkscape \
    libcurl4-nss-dev libssl-dev \
    " \
    && seq 1 8 | xargs -I{} mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man{} \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $RUN_DEPS \
    && python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && mkdir -p /home/${APP_USER}/.config/inkscape \
    && chown -R ${APP_USER} /home/${APP_USER}/.config/inkscape \
    # Create directories
    && mkdir /app/ \
    && mkdir /config/ \
    && mkdir /scripts/ \
    && mkdir -p /static_cdn/static_root/ \
    && chown -R ${APP_USER} /static_cdn/

COPY ./requirements/requirements.txt /

RUN set -ex \
    && BUILD_DEPS=" \
    build-essential \
    libpcre3-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    " \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $BUILD_DEPS \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false $BUILD_DEPS \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./src /app/
COPY pytest.ini /
COPY ./scripts/ /scripts/
COPY ./configs/ /configs/
COPY library_data /library_data

WORKDIR /app/


EXPOSE 8000

ENV UWSGI_WSGI_FILE=app/wsgi.py
ENV UWSGI_HTTP=:8000 UWSGI_MASTER=1 UWSGI_HTTP_AUTO_CHUNKED=1 UWSGI_HTTP_KEEPALIVE=1 UWSGI_LAZY_APPS=1 UWSGI_WSGI_ENV_BEHAVIOR=holy
ENV UWSGI_WORKERS=2 UWSGI_THREADS=4
ENV UWSGI_STATIC_MAP="/static/=/static_cdn/static_root/" UWSGI_STATIC_EXPIRES_URI="/static/.*\.[a-f0-9]{12,}\.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff|ttf|otf|svg|scss|map|txt) 315360000"

# Change to a non-root user
USER ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER}

ENTRYPOINT ["/scripts/docker/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -e

safeRunCommand() {
  cmnd="$*"
  echo cmnd="$cmnd"
  eval "$cmnd"
  ret_code=$?
  if [ $ret_code != 0 ]; then
    printf "Error : [code: %d] when executing command: '$cmnd'\n" $ret_code
    exit $ret_code
  else
    echo "Command run successfully: $cmnd"
  fi
}

runDjangoCollectStatic() {
  echo "Collecting static files"
  cmnd="python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
  safeRunCommand "$cmnd"
  echo "Done: Collecting static files"
}

runDjangoMigrate() {
  echo "Migrating database"
  safeRunCommand "python manage.py migrate --noinput"
  echo "Done: Migrating database"
}

runDjangoCheckDeploy() {
  echo "Checking Django deployment"
  safeRunCommand "python manage.py check --deploy"
  echo "Done: Checking Django deployment"
}

if [ "x$DEPLOYMENT_MODE" = 'xproduction' ]; then
  echo "Running in production mode..."
  runDjangoCheckDeploy
  runDjangoCollectStatic
  runDjangoMigrate
fi

if [ "x$DJANGO_MANAGE_COLLECTSTATIC" = 'xon' ] && [ ! "x$DEPLOYMENT_MODE" = 'xproduction' ]; then
  runDjangoCollectStatic
fi

if [ "x$DJANGO_MANAGE_MIGRATE" = 'xon' ] && [ ! "x$DEPLOYMENT_MODE" = 'xproduction' ]; then
  runDjangoMigrate
fi

# Accept other commands
exec "$@"
```

When the same image is built locally and pushed to ECR, then it works fine without any modification.

By pulling the image from ECR and running locally gives the following warning but the image is running fine locally

```
docker pull ecr/image
docker run -it ecr/image bash

WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
app@fc0e09fc9094:/app$
```

EC2 machine type is AMD (Graviton Processor) (m6g class)

> Edit 2

Running the `uname -m` command on server containers is giving

```
aarch64
```

while the image built in GitHub action is giving

```
x86_64
```

Comment: instead of  `#!/bin/sh` user `#!/bin/bash` in your entrypoint.

Comment: @RajVerma This didn't help. Still getting the same error

Comment: This error actually means, you are trying to run something that is not made for your cpu architecture. check [THIS LINK](https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.9.11-slim/images/sha256-1adba5ab910a0bf9579e39f21019a160cb8da558de001549cafcb71a423b8f97?context=explore) and try a different image

Comment: @RajVerma check Edit 2

Comment: what if you don't use the slim version and use the official python image [HERE](https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=description)

Comment: @RajVerma Same is working fine on other servers and locally. It seems the issue is associated with the build architecture. I checked my previous built image and they are on `aarch64` architecture, while the one built from Github action is `x86_64`.

Comment: Well one thing i know for sure is that error is always for cpu architecture difference. Check if anything in the build environment has changed.

Comment: Github actions only run on x86 machines currently and will build an x86 container by default, I assume your local environment is based on Arm64 which is why it works, but not via github.  You can build arm64 containers on github actions, but need to do it via emulation: https://docs.earthly.dev/docs/guides/multi-platform is a guide on how to set that up.  I've seen this done for python builds in the past to generate binary wheels for multiple architectures, provided the slowdown from emulation is not too severe.